# Does CGminer work with Network miners?

Tags: network, cgminer, proxy

I have the black cube miners that work via cat5/network and have yet to be able to connect them to cgminer. I have looked all over the internet and haven't found anything about how to do it.

- So my question is can CGMiner connect to network miners?
- If so how?

Thanks for the help.